# How to write SQL query for getting distinct values from a single row?

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I have a table which is a result of taking cross product of a single table multiple times. Now I might have duplicates belonging to different columns in a single row. I want to know how to write the query for A != B != C != D where A,B,C,D are column names. How do I write the SQL query for selecting unique values from the same row?

Comment: What is the query?  Don't be shy.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by a very complicated `where` clause or just by putting in appropriate `join` conditions.

Here is an example:

```
select a.col as a, b.col as b, c.col as c, d.col as d
from table a join
     table b
     on b.col <> a.col join
     table c
     on c.col not in (a.col, b.col) join
     table d
     on d.col not in (a.col, b.col, c.col);
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89dc4/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( val ) AS
SELECT LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT A.val AS A_val,
       B.val AS B_val,
       C.val AS C_val,
       D.val AS D_val
FROM   test A
       CROSS JOIN test b
       CROSS JOIN test c
       CROSS JOIN test d
WHERE  A.val NOT IN ( b.val, c.val, d.val )
AND    B.val NOT IN ( c.val, d.val )
AND    C.val <> D.val
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89dc4/1/0)**:

```
| A_VAL | B_VAL | C_VAL | D_VAL |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|     1 |     2 |     3 |     4 |
|     1 |     2 |     3 |     5 |
|     1 |     2 |     4 |     3 |
|     1 |     2 |     4 |     5 |
|     1 |     2 |     5 |     3 |
|     1 |     2 |     5 |     4 |
|     1 |     3 |     2 |     4 |
|     1 |     3 |     2 |     5 |
|     1 |     3 |     4 |     2 |
|     1 |     3 |     4 |     5 |
|     1 |     3 |     5 |     2 |
|     1 |     3 |     5 |     4 |
|     1 |     4 |     2 |     3 |
|     1 |     4 |     2 |     5 |
|     1 |     4 |     3 |     2 |
|     1 |     4 |     3 |     5 |
|     1 |     4 |     5 |     2 |
|     1 |     4 |     5 |     3 |
|     1 |     5 |     2 |     3 |
|     1 |     5 |     2 |     4 |
|     1 |     5 |     3 |     2 |
|     1 |     5 |     3 |     4 |
|     1 |     5 |     4 |     2 |
|     1 |     5 |     4 |     3 |
|     2 |     1 |     3 |     4 |
|     2 |     1 |     3 |     5 |
|     2 |     1 |     4 |     3 |
|     2 |     1 |     4 |     5 |
|     2 |     1 |     5 |     3 |
|     2 |     1 |     5 |     4 |
|     2 |     3 |     1 |     4 |
|     2 |     3 |     1 |     5 |
|     2 |     3 |     4 |     1 |
|     2 |     3 |     4 |     5 |
|     2 |     3 |     5 |     1 |
|     2 |     3 |     5 |     4 |
|     2 |     4 |     1 |     3 |
|     2 |     4 |     1 |     5 |
|     2 |     4 |     3 |     1 |
|     2 |     4 |     3 |     5 |
|     2 |     4 |     5 |     1 |
|     2 |     4 |     5 |     3 |
|     2 |     5 |     1 |     3 |
|     2 |     5 |     1 |     4 |
|     2 |     5 |     3 |     1 |
|     2 |     5 |     3 |     4 |
|     2 |     5 |     4 |     1 |
|     2 |     5 |     4 |     3 |
|     3 |     1 |     2 |     4 |
|     3 |     1 |     2 |     5 |
|     3 |     1 |     4 |     2 |
|     3 |     1 |     4 |     5 |
|     3 |     1 |     5 |     2 |
|     3 |     1 |     5 |     4 |
|     3 |     2 |     1 |     4 |
|     3 |     2 |     1 |     5 |
|     3 |     2 |     4 |     1 |
|     3 |     2 |     4 |     5 |
|     3 |     2 |     5 |     1 |
|     3 |     2 |     5 |     4 |
|     3 |     4 |     1 |     2 |
|     3 |     4 |     1 |     5 |
|     3 |     4 |     2 |     1 |
|     3 |     4 |     2 |     5 |
|     3 |     4 |     5 |     1 |
|     3 |     4 |     5 |     2 |
|     3 |     5 |     1 |     2 |
|     3 |     5 |     1 |     4 |
|     3 |     5 |     2 |     1 |
|     3 |     5 |     2 |     4 |
|     3 |     5 |     4 |     1 |
|     3 |     5 |     4 |     2 |
|     4 |     1 |     2 |     3 |
|     4 |     1 |     2 |     5 |
|     4 |     1 |     3 |     2 |
|     4 |     1 |     3 |     5 |
|     4 |     1 |     5 |     2 |
|     4 |     1 |     5 |     3 |
|     4 |     2 |     1 |     3 |
|     4 |     2 |     1 |     5 |
|     4 |     2 |     3 |     1 |
|     4 |     2 |     3 |     5 |
|     4 |     2 |     5 |     1 |
|     4 |     2 |     5 |     3 |
|     4 |     3 |     1 |     2 |
|     4 |     3 |     1 |     5 |
|     4 |     3 |     2 |     1 |
|     4 |     3 |     2 |     5 |
|     4 |     3 |     5 |     1 |
|     4 |     3 |     5 |     2 |
|     4 |     5 |     1 |     2 |
|     4 |     5 |     1 |     3 |
|     4 |     5 |     2 |     1 |
|     4 |     5 |     2 |     3 |
|     4 |     5 |     3 |     1 |
|     4 |     5 |     3 |     2 |
|     5 |     1 |     2 |     3 |
|     5 |     1 |     2 |     4 |
|     5 |     1 |     3 |     2 |
|     5 |     1 |     3 |     4 |
|     5 |     1 |     4 |     2 |
|     5 |     1 |     4 |     3 |
|     5 |     2 |     1 |     3 |
|     5 |     2 |     1 |     4 |
|     5 |     2 |     3 |     1 |
|     5 |     2 |     3 |     4 |
|     5 |     2 |     4 |     1 |
|     5 |     2 |     4 |     3 |
|     5 |     3 |     1 |     2 |
|     5 |     3 |     1 |     4 |
|     5 |     3 |     2 |     1 |
|     5 |     3 |     2 |     4 |
|     5 |     3 |     4 |     1 |
|     5 |     3 |     4 |     2 |
|     5 |     4 |     1 |     2 |
|     5 |     4 |     1 |     3 |
|     5 |     4 |     2 |     1 |
|     5 |     4 |     2 |     3 |
|     5 |     4 |     3 |     1 |
|     5 |     4 |     3 |     2 |
```